# Gradle use SLF4J simple for tests and Log4j12 for runtime

Tags: gradle, slf4j

I am using slf4j during my tests I would like to see the log output on the console by using slf4j simple. Then runtime will use a log4j configuration.

I was able to do this in maven by declaring the dependencies like so

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency> 
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
  <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>    
<dependency> 
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
  <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

I have tried doing something similar for Gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile "org.slf4j:slf4j-api:$SLF4J_VERSION"
    testCompile "org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:$SLF4J_VERSION"
    runtime "org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:$SLF4J_VERSION"
}
```

However during the build I can see it's still using the Log4j12 implementation. How do I fix this?

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J providers.
SLF4J: Found provider [org.slf4j.log4j12.Log4j12ServiceProvider@4ad9cc78]
SLF4J: Found provider [org.slf4j.simple.SimpleServiceProvider@6e869e5e]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual provider is of type [org.slf4j.log4j12.Log4j12ServiceProvider@4ad9cc78]
```

Comment: Is this happening at gradle command line? Or only in your IDE?

Comment: I do it via command line

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
gradle dependencies --configuration testRuntime
```

To see where it's coming from

Comment: `gradle dependencyInsight --configuration testRuntime --dependency slf4j-log4j12` gives 'No dependencies matching given input were found in configuration ':testRuntime'

Comment: Yup 'Dependency insight report cannot be generated because the dependency to show was not specified.'

Comment: Whoops, try `gradle dependencies --configuration testRuntime`. I always get those two tasks confused

Comment: hmmm that latest one shows slf4j-log4j12 as a root dependency as if I explicitly declared it as testRuntim?!?!

Comment: If I change the log4j dependency to runtimeOnly it no longer shows in the dependencies output but still seems to be in the classpath come the tests.

Comment: See [java plugin dependency management](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_plugin_and_dependency_management) "testRuntime(Deprecated) extends runtime, testCompile
Additional dependencies for running tests only. Used by task test. Superseded by testRuntimeOnly"

Comment: thanks but I've already tried to change runtime->runtimeOnly, compile -> implementation, testRuntime -> testRuntimeOnly , and testCompile-> testImplementation. Using the dependencies command no longer shows log4j but it's still on the classpath being pulled in from the gradle cache.

Comment: This is really wierd, will add another answer

Answer (score 1):

Another suggestion, add this to one of your tests

```
String path = "org/slf4j/log4j12/Log4j12ServiceProvider.class";
Enumeration<URL> urls = getClass().getClassLoader().getResources(path);
while (urls.hasMoreElements()) {
    System.out.println(String.format("found %s at %s", path, urls.nextElement()));
}
```

Comment: That gives ` found org/slf4j/log4j12/Log4j12ServiceProvider.class at jar:file:/C:/Users/Paul/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.8.0-beta2/ee99e18c77147a4d7619a06683e70e741b95641b/slf4j-log4j12-1.8.0-beta2.jar!/org/slf4j/log4j12/Log4j12ServiceProvider.class`

Comment: This looks like version `1.8.0-beta2` does that match your `SLF4J_VERSION`? Or is it different?

Comment: yup matches the version

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the feeling that somehow the buildscript classpath is leaking into the junit classpath somehow. Try adding this to your build.gradle

```
task showInConfigurations {
   doLast {
      String path = "org/slf4j/log4j12/Log4j12ServiceProvider.class"
      def configs = [buildscript.configurations.classpath, configurations.testRuntime]
      configs.each { config ->
         config.files.each { file ->
            if (file.name.endsWith('.jar')) {
               Set<File> matches = zipTree(file).matching { include path}.files
               if (matches) println "Found $path in $config.name in $file" 
            } 
         } 
       } 
    } 
}
```

If its not in the `testRuntime` Configuration I think you might've found a gradle bug.

Comment: I get no output with that

Comment: This is untested. Perhaps try adding "org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:$SLF4J_VERSION" to testRuntime dependencies then run `gradle showInConfigurations` just to sanity test